# Sharepoint Modern Site - Call JS Function After Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I've searched for a solution but only found solutions for other versions of sharepoint.

Pages are modern sharepoint template, inside a modern script editor webpart i'm laoding my .js file.
Sometimes the function is called, sometimes it's not. On refreshing the page, the function fires.

These did not work

```
$(document).ready
window.onload
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", myFunction);
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction, "sp.js");
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myFunction");
```

Anyone have any idea how to fire functions after sharepoint is actually loaded?

Answer (score 1):

With SPFX you have the option to include jQuery or you can do it with just regular browser core JavaScript API.

I used the following to override the search textbox on SP modern to be able to use the search center results page since Microsoft forgot that they provide a Search Center Override Url setting in the settings page and don't actually use it in modern for some whacky reason that someone should totally get a hand slappin for.

```
/*
Because modern does funky html stuff you'll wanna wait until your specific html element you need to work with is available to be worked with.
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(doesThatDarnSearchBoxExistYetOrWhat, 150);
});


function doesThatDarnSearchBoxExistYetOrWhat() {
   var $search = $(".ms-compositeHeader-searchBoxContainer");
   if($search === null) {
     //Not found, keep waiting.
     setTimeout(doesThatDarnSearchBoxExistYetOrWhat, 150);
   } else {
     // Found, fix that.
     getTheModernSpSearchTheHeckOuttaMyFace();
   }
}

function getTheModernSpSearchTheHeckOuttaMyFace() {

  //Strip events on search form
  $(".ms-compositeHeader-searchBoxContainer").html($(".ms-compositeHeader-searchBoxContainer").html())

  $form = $(".ms-compositeHeader-searchBoxContainer FORM");

  //Change submission to search center results page
  $form.attr("action","/sites/Search-Center/Pages/results.aspx")

  //Change textbox name to "k" for search param.
  $form.find("input[type='search']").attr("name","k")

}
```